# how to share image from sever to whatsapp

Tags: android, image, android-intent, whatsapp

hey guys i want to share image from server to whatsapp but its give an error image share failed can you tell me can i share image directly server to whatsapp what i am doing something wrong

this is my code

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
            Uri imageUri = Uri.parse("http://stacktoheap.com/images/stackoverflow.png");  // here is my selected url
            shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            shareIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
            shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, img_txt);
            shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUri);
            shareIntent.setType("image/*");
            shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
            try {
                context.startActivity(shareIntent);
            } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
                context.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.whatsapp")));
            }
```

help me friends

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my answer is simple first download image from sever and then share image on whatsapp

try this code

```
String imagePath =Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "your folderpath"+"imagename";
        File f=new File(imagePath);
        Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(f);
        Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        share.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
        share.setType("image/jpg");
        share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"your text");  //want share text with image
        share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
        share.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        try {
            startActivity(share);
        } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.whatsapp")));
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting issue because you are sharing image and text both

Infact whatsapp doesn't allow to share image and text simultaneously, try either image only